# Как разбить значения по колонкам в csv файле при помощи Python

Tags: python, csv

У меня есть код:

```
 @manager.command
 def list_routes():
 import urllib
 import csv
 for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
    options = {}
    for arg in rule.arguments:
        options[arg] = "[{0}]".format(arg)
    url = rule.rule
    line = urllib.parse.unquote("{}{} ".format(rule.endpoint, url))

    with open('urls.cvs', 'a') as out:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(out, lineterminator='', dialect='excel')
        spamwriter.writerows(line)
        spamwriter.writerows('\n')
```

Мне нужно заполнить cvs файл так, что бы rule.endpoint и url были отдельными колонками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
@manager.command
def list_routes():
    with open('urls.csv', 'w') as out:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(out, lineterminator='\n')
        csv_writer.writerows([[rule.endpoint, rule.rule] for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules()])
```

Answer (score 2):

вот как у меня реализованно

```
with open('projects2.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    writer.writerow(('Объект', 'Цена', 'Телефон'))

    writer.writerows(
        (obekt['title'], obekt['price'], obekt['tel']) for obekt in obekts
    )
```

Comment: выдает ошибку : string indices must be integers

Comment: строковый индексы должны быть цифрами. у меня obetk - словарь

Comment: у меня текст и цифры

Comment: напиши пример содержания line.

Comment: factory_packaging.download/project/<int:project_id>.<int:workflow_id>/factory/packaging/download/<unique_hash>/<type>/<int:id>/

**rule.endpoint** - factory_packaging.download
**url** - /project/<int:project_id>.<int:workflow_id>/factory/packaging/download/<unique_hash>/<type>/<int:id>/

Comment: import csv
    line = ["factory_packaging.download","URL"]
    csvfile = open('line.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(('Объект', 'URL'))
    writer.writerow((line[0], line[1]))
    csvfile.close()